# Do we have any opensource SMS / Call Sending API like RingCentral API?

Tags: java, sms, ringcentral

RingCentral API is very good solution for sending SMS or making calls out. Wondering if we have any open source frameworks similar to RingCentral?

Answer (score 0):

Plivo is another, but why aren't you going with RingCentral? What needs isn't it meeting?